# What is equivalent to this in function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using function component ,and now I want to pass itself to another objects.

```
import GlobalParam from './GlobalParam'
const TopPage = (props) =>{
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() =>{
    GlobalParam.topPage = this;// however it does not work in function component.

  })
}
```

in GlobalParam

```
export default class GlobalParam {
   static topPage;
}
```

If I can pass conponent function itself to static class,

I can load the topPage from anywhere `GlobalParam.topPage.setLoad(true);`

What should I use in function component instead of `this`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to roll your own global state management.  You'll likely find it *much* simpler to use something like Redux or a top-level `useContext` instead.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify "*I want to pass itself to another objects*". What is your goal? What do you want the other objects to be able to do? What if there are multiple instances of your `<TopPage>`?

Comment: If you're looking for a simple/fun state management tool [`signals`](https://preactjs.com/blog/introducing-signals/) is new and really useful. Originally only available for Preact [here's the React implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@preact/signals-react).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext).

You can define a context with `createContext` (you can specify defaultValue but it's out of the scope of this example)

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const LoadContext = createContext();

export default LoadContext;
```

Then you can wrap your app with a Provider that will make available variables and functions to all its children

```js
import TopPage from './TopPage';
import Debug from './DebugButton';
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import LoadContext from './LoadContext';


function App() {

  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false)

  return (
    <LoadContext.Provider value={{load, setLoad}}>
      <TopPage />
      <Debug />
    </LoadContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and then you can access the context with `useContext` hook!

```js
import {useContext} from 'react';
import LoadContext from './LoadContext';

const TopPage = (props) => {
  
  const {load} = useContext(LoadContext)

  return (
    <div>
      {load? <h1>loading</h1>: <h1>not loading</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopPage;
```

and another component I made just for testing purpose

```js
import { useContext } from "react"
import LoadContext from "./LoadContext"

const DebugButton = () => {
  const {setLoad} = useContext(LoadContext)

  return <button onClick={()=>{setLoad(v=>!v)}}>Debug</button>
}

export default DebugButton
```

Comment: I can solve my problem with useContext(). It's quite useful and I had better use this many places else.Until now  I path value step by step to every nested components....